# How to define By element xpath using another By element using Selenium WebDriver

Tags: selenium, xpath

I want to definde a By element xpath, using previously defined By element.

Example:
I have a following By Element defined:

```
private By firstExpander = By.xpath("//div[@id = 'language-expander']");
```

Now I want to define another By element, that is a child in the DOM structure of this element, for example the Name of this 'language-expander'. I have tried following:

```
private By firstExpanderName = By.xpath(firstExpander.toString() + "/div[1]/a");
```

but it includes the "By.xpath" part of the parent in the resulting string. And I'm sure I'm doing this wrong. Any suggestion on how to do this properly?

Comment: You should add tags for programming language and framework you use to make your issue more specific avoid solutions that are correct, but not applicable in your particular case

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
String div = "//div[@id = 'language-expander']";
private By firstExpander = By.xpath(div);
private By firstExpanderName = By.xpath(div + "/div[1]/a");
```

Answer (score 0):

Assign the parent xpath string to a variable. Later you can append any string to that to derive child xpath.

Answer (score 0):

Please try it this way -

```
private By firstExpanderName = firstExpander.findElement(By.xpath(".//div[1]/a"))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WebElement wb1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath(""));
WebElement wb2 = wb1.findElement(By.xpath(""));
wb2.[YourAction]
```

Comment: Hi Hemant; your code might be correct, but with some context it would make a better answer; for example, you could explain how and why this proposed change would resolve the questioner's problem, perhaps including a link to the relevant documentation. That would make it more useful to them, and also more useful to other site readers who are looking for solutions to similar problems.

Comment: Here we are trying to find child object those presents on parent object, hence in above explanation wb1 will be parent object whereas wb2 should be child object(s), you may want to use wb2 as list if it is expected that child objects are more than one. Thank you.